# Creating global environment objects from two lists

Tags: r

I am having an issue assigning variable objects to a list of data frames. For example,

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 1:10)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 2, b = 1:10)
df3 <- data.frame(a = 3, b = 1:10)

x <- c("a", "b", "c")
y <- list("df1", "df2", "df3")
```

My goal is to assign each data frame in the y list to the object in x. I can do it long hand.

```
a <- y[[1]]
```

But I have many iterations. I have tried the following without any luck

```
map2(x, y, function(x, y) x <- y)
```

and

```
map2(x, y, ~assign(x, y))
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

We can `unlist` the `list` of object names (`unlist(y)`), get the values with `mget` in a `list`, set the names of the `list` elements with 'x' vector values and use `list2env` to create objects in the global env (not recommended though)

```
list2env(setNames(mget(unlist(y)), x), .GlobalEnv)
```

---

If we use `map2`, then we need to `get` the value of 'y' and also specify the `envir`onment to `assign` the value

```
map2(x, y, ~ assign(.x, get(.y), envir = .GlobalEnv))
```

-output

```
a
#   a  b
#1  1  1
#2  1  2
#3  1  3
#4  1  4
#5  1  5
#6  1  6
#7  1  7
#8  1  8
#9  1  9
#10 1 10

b
#   a  b
#1  2  1
#2  2  2
#3  2  3
#4  2  4
#5  2  5
#6  2  6
#7  2  7
#8  2  8
#9  2  9
#10 2 10
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Why is it not recommended to create the objects in the global environment?

Comment: @JakeBernards You could do the same in a `list` and store it, or write back as csv without lots of objects in the global env

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the above options didn't work in my case. I ended up adapting the suggestions made by akrun which worked.

```
names(y) <- x
list2env(y, envir=.GlobalEnv)
```